# PHP-Dynamically add the name of the file in addattachment PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i'm familiar with phpmailer and it's addattachment method but I don't know how to add the name of the file dynamically?

```
$m->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'I want the name of the file here');
```

rest of the code as same as [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps)

I want that when the user chooses his file the name of the file appears dynamically in the method.

Comment: define *"dynamically"*. You gave us "one" line of code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- made the change could now help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original filename is stored in `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`. So code you need is:

```
$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Comment: yes it worked.....I also wanted to know what is the max file size using addattachment in phpmailer or is there a way to increase the file size?

Comment: when I upload a file say more than 500KB it gives me this error: Failed to move file to C:\Windows\Temp\7e12C1E.tmp